# Automate Task app to change the ADSL Modem Setting (Every Day)

Tags: networking, task-management

According [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232596/scheduling-method-for-guest-network-in-tplink-td-w8960n-adsl-modem?noredirect=1#comment475457_232596) question:

[image]

I like to know what automate Task app in Ubuntu, you recommend to open the AdSL modem setting and automatically tick the gust network option in the modem IP address?

I have seen [this](https://www.linuxtechi.com/top-7-tools-automate-linux-admin-task/) site about:

[Top 7 Tools that can automate Linux Admin Task](https://www.linuxtechi.com/top-7-tools-automate-linux-admin-task/)

Which i think have had my answer but i lie to know your suggestion Also.

**Update:**

I want to change **the Guest network**'s enable option to disable and vise versa in this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGoLl.png), by schedule time table for every day automatically. 
As you can see below:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a little more detail about what exactly you want. Do you want the internet connection to be switched off and on at certain times of the day? A simple hardware timer could possibly do that. Your Top 7 tools are not going to do that unless your TP-Link router supports SNMP, which I doubt. It is quite a consumer-oriented device. However, the router listens to `telnet` which would allow you to change its configuration. You would need to ask around [here](https://community.tp-link.com/en) to find out what the proper command would be. Then, it's a question of running a cron job.

Comment: I want to change the ADSL modem setting from **http://192.168.1.1/** Address for every day for example at 2 O'clock.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you want to do that? What problem would this solve?

Comment: you can see more info at the main question [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232596/scheduling-method-for-guest-network-in-tplink-td-w8960n-adsl-modem?noredirect=1#comment475457_232596), but i want to share my internet by others via guest network.

Comment: There is no more info at that link, but I would guess you want to enable/disable the guest network setting at a given time, not change the IP address of the router, which would completely break all network connections at once.

Comment: yes, i want to change the enable option to disable and vise versa in this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGoLl.png)

Comment: According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1145685/deactivate-a-tp-link-modem-router-access-point-through-telnet) the CLI should be very similar to that of a Zyxel modem, which is documented [here](ftp://ftp2.zyxel.com/P-660W-T1_v2/cli_reference_guide/P-660W-T1%20v2_1.pdf).